# Wifi stays Disable in HP X360 i5

Tags: wifi

I have checked all the solutions mentioned on this website but none worked for me. WIFI stays disabled. Pls. find attached below picture for the reference.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, but no output if rfkill list. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal `echo "blacklist acer-wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf`
Reboot and wireless should function.

For some reason some HP laptops will load the acer-wmi module and have issues with a soft block on an acer-wireless device

Answer (score 0):

I own the same computer and I can confirm the same wi-fi issue; the previous answer fix it;
you can also fix it by typing:

`sudo rmmod acer_wmi`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `blacklist acer_wmi` at the bottom

hit ctr^o + enter to save; ctr^x to exit

reboot, done.